# Submenu items appearing behind content area

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a website. I have created a vertical drop down menu but when I hover my mouse on the menu the sub items doesn't show up perfectly -- the sub menus appears to go behind my content area (please check the image below).

[image]

But if I remove the content, the menu shows up correctly. It looks like following:

[image]

I have pasted all the codes in http://jsfiddle.net/SxWbD/2/ .

Would you please kindly tell me where I am doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just give your #sidebar - z-index:10;

http://jsfiddle.net/SxWbD/3/

Comment: Thank you very much Praveen Vijayan. It is now working perfectly. Thanks again.. would you mind if I ask you how z-index:10; made the difference here? :)

Comment: In your code both main & sidebar has position relative. Higher z-index will bring the sidebar forward. Any value above 0 will work there, since main didn't have a z-index (value is 0 by default).